# R: Remove repeated values and keep the first one in a binary vector

Tags: r, indexing, duplicates

I would like to remove the repeated ones but keep the first in a binary vector:

```
x = c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1) # the input 
y = c(0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)     # the desired output
```

i.e., one `1` and two `1`'s of the first and third set of `1`'s are removed, respectively, and the first in the set is kept.

I am trying to use `rle` with `cumsum` but have not yet figured it out. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: here's another one `x[ave(x, cumsum(x == 0), FUN = cumsum) <= 1]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `rle`/`inverse.rle`

```
res <- rle(x)
res$lengths[res$values == 1] <- 1
inverse.rle(res)
## [1] 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: Or `inverse.rle(within(unclass(rle(x)),lengths[values==1]<-1))` to make it a one-liner.

Comment: @nicola yeah I was thinking to make it a one liner but was trying to do `with(rle(x), lengths[values == 1] <- 1)` which doesn't work for some reason. Using `within` with `unclass` seems like hard to read.

Comment: Didn't know there is an inverse one, great!

Answer (score 8):

We can use `diff`:

```
x[c(1, diff(x)) == 1 | x == 0]
```

Comment: If one wants to subset a data frame, it is awesome to keep the indices if the vector is one of the column. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4):

```
x = c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1)
x[!(x == 1 & #remove each value that is a 1
    c(x[-1] == 1, FALSE) #followed by a 1 (never the case for the last value)
  )]
#[1] 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: This is obviously more concise than my answer. Can you explain how this works?

Comment: @BrantMullinix I've added comments.

Comment: Why do you have the vector c(x[-1]==1,FALSE)? What is the difference from just doing  x[!(x == 1 & x[-1] == 1)]?

Comment: For anyone else wondering the same I found the answer myself. x[-1] returns a vector without the first element so when you & this with the first part the vector lengths differ. While R can handle this on it's own it has implications and is not recommended. To resolve the issue @Roland added a FALSE to the end of the vector since the last value will be false in this comparison. This makes the two vectors equal length and avoids the warning "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length".

Answer (score 1):

```
x = c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1)
x1 <- rle(x)
x1$lengths[x1$values==1] <- 1
inverse.rle(x1)
```

Comment: This was the version I was about to post.

Comment: @David Arenburg is quicker

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the vector size you could loop through it and use conditions for appending the value to the result. Here is a simple solution using your given input.

```
x <- c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1)
prev <- 0
y <- c()
for(i in x){
  if (i == 1){
    if (prev != 1){
      y <- append(y,i)
    }
  }else{
    y <- append(y,i)
  }
  prev <- i
}
```

Comment: Never grow an object in a loop. Please read [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. @Roland